# ANT FTP build command fails due to unresolved oro dependency

Tags: java, ant, ftp

I want to use FTP tag in my ANT command to receive files from FTP location. To enable this I copied `jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar` and `apache-commons-net.jar` in the lib folder of my ANT. While running the command I get following error:  `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation` problems:

```
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.oro cannot be resolved
    Pattern cannot be resolved to a type
    MatchResult cannot be resolved to a type
    PatternMatcher cannot be resolved to a type
    _matcher_ cannot be resolved
    Perl5Matcher cannot be resolved to a type
    pattern cannot be resolved
    Perl5Compiler cannot be resolved to a type
    MalformedPatternException cannot be resolved to a type
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    _matcher_ cannot be resolved
    pattern cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    _matcher_ cannot be resolved
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field
    result cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(RegexFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:19)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.<init>(ConfigurableFTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.UnixFTPEntryParser.<init>(UnixFTPEntryParser.java:136)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.UnixFTPEntryParser.<init>(UnixFTPEntryParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createUnixFTPEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2359)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2142)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2188)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP$FTPDirectoryScanner.forceRemoteSensitivityCheck(FTP.java:695)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP$FTPDirectoryScanner.scan(FTP.java:372)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP.transferFiles(FTP.java:1738)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP.transferFiles(FTP.java:1850)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP.execute(FTP.java:2539)
```

Why Ant fails to import the ORO dependency?

Comment: What version of ANT are you using?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.6.5\bin>ant -v
Apache Ant version 1.6.5 compiled on June 2 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANT 1.6.5 is a very old version of ANT. The following example was tested with ANT 1.9.0:

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

   <target name="bootstrap">
      <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/commons-net.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=commons-net/commons-net/3.3/commons-net-3.3.jar"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/oro.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar"/>
   </target>

   <target name="build">
      <ftp server="ftp.apache.org" userid="anonymous" password="me@myorg.com">
         <fileset dir="htdocs/manual"/>
      </ftp>
   </target>

</project>
```

The bootstrap target installs the missing ftp task dependencies into a location that ANT will use, next time it runs.